# Confirm that the user account was deleted do not work

Tags: php, mysql

I have a delete account page that allow the users to delete their accounts after checking if the password is correct but the problem is 
when the user insert a wrong password the system display an error msg that the password is not correct. 
When the user inserts a correct password the system does not display any message to inform the user.
Can anyone help me?

## delete_account.php

```
<?php 
session_start();
$msgToUser="";
if(@!$_SESSION['user_id'])
{
    $msgToUser= '<br /><br /><font color = "#FF000">Only registered users can delete their account</font><p><a href = "register.php">Join Here</a></p>';
    exit();
}
$id = $_SESSION['user_id'];

if(isset($_POST['delete']))
{


        $del_acct_pass = $_POST['del_account_pass'];
         require_once('include/connect.php'); 
        $check_pass = mysql_query("SELECT password FROM user WHERE password = '$del_acct_pass' AND user_id ='$id'")or die(mysql_error());
        $check_pass_num = mysql_num_rows($check_pass);
        if($check_pass_num>0)
        {
        /*$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user  WHERE user_id = '$id'")or die(mysql_error());
        $pass_check_num = mysql_num_rows($sql);*/


            $pic1=("members/$id/image01.jpg");
            if(file_exists($pic1))
            { 
                  unlink($pic1);

            }

            $dir = "members/$id";
            rmdir($dir);

            $sqltable1 = mysql_query("DELETE FROM user WHERE user_id ='$id'")or die(mysql_error());
            $sqltable1 = mysql_query("DELETE FROM blabing WHERE u_id ='$id'")or die(mysql_error());
            $msgToUser="<h3 style='color:#99FF33'>YOUR Account Has Been Deleted!!!</h3>";
            session_destroy();



        }
        $msgToUser = "<h3 style='color:#CC0000'>YOU must Write the correct Password</h3>";

}



?>
  <table width="70%" align="center" cellpadding="6">
          <form action="delete_account.php" method="post" name="delete_form" >
            <tr>
              <td bgcolor="#CCCCCC">Delete Your Account </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Please enter Your current Password to proceed with account deletion</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><input type="password" name="del_account_pass" id="del_account_pass" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>

              <td><input type="submit" name="delete" id="delete" value="Delete Account" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td><?php echo $msgToUser; ?></td>
            </tr>
            </form>
          </table>
```

Comment: check your code again, in my opinion your code is completely wrong!
for example if delete process is ok then it echos "YOU must Write the correct Password" in every conditions, it's correct or not!

Answer (score 1):

You are setting $msgToUser always to the message abouyt incorrect password, always.

It runs even when it deletes the account.

You probably want it in a Else clause

```
} else {
    $msgToUser = "<h3 style='color:#CC0000'>YOU must Write the correct Password</h3>";
}
```

Btw, the you need to read up on security, your code is vulnerable to SQL injection.